# What is the optimal way to merge many Dataframes in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have N (100-1K) of huge Dataframes (100GB - 1T each) and need to process each of them and get a small dataframe (couple of MB) and union the processed dataframes. Is there a more optimal way of doing it that this:

```
df_merged = new_empty_df

for i in range(N):
    df_raw = read(i)
    df_processed = process(df_raw)
    df_merged = df_merged.union(df_processed) # should .persist() be used here?

# output processed
df_merged.write(somewhere)
```

Also, should .persist() be used in the 3rd line of the loop to speed things up?

Edit 1:
Here' more information about the data and what's happening inside the `process`.
Data is tsv/parquet containing GPS locations:

| Location |
| --- |
| POINT (30 10) |
| POINT (33.44 -22.4) |
| POINT (33.11 -21.7) |

The `process` first calculates AreaId for each Location point. It's applied to every row.

| Location | AreaId |
| --- | --- |
| POINT (30 10) | 2 |
| POINT (33.44 -22.4) | 4 |
| POINT (33.11 -21.7) | 4 |

Then, I need want to calculate the number of points inside each AreaId, resulting in the following:

| AreaId | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

The code I used for those 2 things is:

```
df_area_id= df_raw.withColumn('AreaId',GetTileForPointUDF(col('Location')))
        
df_processed = df_area_id.groupby('AreaId').count()
```

Comment: Few question , is column are same in all dataframe , what is data format and how long one dataframe take to process

Comment: `Persist` be used in the 3rd line is one of the ways that improve the performance. However, I believe the logic in your `process` function is the most important part. Could you share more about the logic inside and provide same sample data?

Comment: I've added more information to address your questions @vaquarkhan and jonathan-lin . Hopefully now there's more context on how to write this optimally.

Comment: @Alcibiades I notice that you use a UDF `GetTileForPointUDF` to get the area id. Are you using some external library to calculate? Or is it a self defined logic? I think we can modify this part since using pyspark api is faster than UDF if we can.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in persist as you are using your dataframes only once.  Your query is already optimal. For example, a similar query gives the following plan.

```
def process(df):
 return  df.withColumn("id", F.col("id") + 1)

df_merged = spark.range(0)
N = 3

for i in range(N):
    df_raw = spark.range(i+1)
    df_processed = process(df_raw)
    df_merged = df_merged.union(df_processed)
```

---

```cpp
 == Physical Plan ==
     Union
     :- *(1) Range (0, 0, step=1, splits=400)     // new_empty_df
     :- *(2) Project [(id#132L + 1) AS id#134L]   // process raw 1
     :  +- *(2) Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=400)  // read raw 1
     :- *(3) Project [(id#137L + 1) AS id#139L]   // process raw 2
     :  +- *(3) Range (0, 2, step=1, splits=400)  // read raw 2
     +- *(4) Project [(id#142L + 1) AS id#144L]   // process raw 3
        +- *(4) Range (0, 3, step=1, splits=400)  // read raw 3
```

Comment: If I were to output the final `df_merged` to multiple outputs with different formats, would it be better if it was persisted?
```df_merged.write.csv(...)
df_merged.write.parquet(...)```

Comment: @Alcibiades in that case yes, because your df_merged will be triggered twice. Persist dataframe, than trigger it by calling 'count', than save
`df_cached = df_merged.persist()`
`df_cached.count()`
`df_cached.write.csv(...)`
`df_cached.write.parquet(...)`